# IntelliJ - how to get the classpath for a module

Tags: intellij-idea

I'm new to IntelliJ and working on a big project with hundreds of modules, I was just wondering how would I get the classpath for a specific module?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? Why do you need it and in what form?

Answer (score 0):

It might help you. Because each module has its own independent classpath. You can combine the classpaths of all modules in the project, and that's what that method did, but trying to use that classpath is unlikely to result in correct behavior in multi-module projects.

```
public static String getFullClassPath(Module m){
String cp = "";
cp += CompilerPaths.getModuleOutputPath(m,false);

for(VirtualFile vf : OrderEnumerator.orderEntries(m).recursively().getClassesRoots()){
    String entry = new File(vf.getPath()).getAbsolutePath();
    if(entry.endsWith("!/")){ //not sure why it happens in the returned paths
        entry = entry.substring(0,entry.length()-2);
    }
    if(entry.endsWith("!")){
        entry = entry.substring(0,entry.length()-1);
    }
    cp += File.pathSeparator + entry;
}
return cp;
```

}